# filter is not a function

Tags: reactjs, function, redux, filter

```
const featureData = action.payload.filter((curElem) => {
  return`your text` curElem.featured === true;   
});
```

How it solved

Console show this

```
Uncaught TypeError: action.payload.filter is not a function
```

Comment: the reason: `payload` is not an array.

Comment: As @MarioVernari already mentionen, it seems `action.payload` is not of type `array`. Please check the type of `action.payload` and add it to your question.